# Excel function that returns the closest number to zero without rounding

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a function that returns the closest value to zero from from a range e.g A1 - A10.

I have found solutions for this on other websites however the value that is returned is rounded to no decimal places.

For my purposes I need the closest value to zero that retains up to ten decimal places.

I have tried the formula:

```
=INDEX(A1:A15,MATCH(SMALL(INDEX(ABS(A1:A15),0,1),COUNTIF(A1:A15,0)+1),INDEX(ABS(A1:A15),0,1),0))
```

however, If say the closest value is -1.0896 It will return -1 not -1.0896

I have a vba procedure changing the values in the range. so a vba solution that saves the closest value to zero to a variable would work.

Comment: Why don't you show us what you've tried so far. It should be a trivial matter to modify one of the other functions...

Comment: BTW: Questions begging for full-blown solutions are frowned upon here. Please demonstrate that you've put forth some effort towards the problem, including your previous attempt(s) and where they have failed or are otherwise incomplete.

Comment: =INDEX(A1:A15,MATCH(SMALL(INDEX(ABS(A1:A15),0,1),COUNTIF(A1:A15,0)+1),INDEX(ABS(A1:A15),0,1),0))

Comment: that's not VBA, that's a worksheet function. Perhaps ask this Q on SuperUser instead. Or, if you're actually doing VBA, show your *code*.  Please put revisions/etc in the original question, it's impossible to read them in the comments.

Comment: The problem with this formula is say the closest value is 3.287 it will return 3 and I require a formula that returns 3.287

Comment: Brute force iteration over the range should work especially if the range is not particularly large. Have you considered something as simple as that?

Comment: The range is large (H1 - H10000)

Comment: 10k isn't that large... or, copy/paste the range to a hidden/temporary worksheet, then sort ascending. THere's like 30 different ways to solve this problem...

Comment: Sort ascending will not work as the range contains large negative values

Comment: noted @pnuts I forget that sometime. Still stands to reason though that any [vba] tag is inappropriate for this Q, if it is strictly a formula question.

Comment: {=MAX(IF(ABS(H1:H10000)=MIN(ABS(H1:H10000)),H1:H10000))}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use your solution from your question it seems to work, it does not round -1.002 to -1, it shows -1.002 if that is the closest to 0. However an alternative:

It isn't very pretty but if you need it to retain the negative value then this should work:

`{=IF(MIN(ABS(A1:A25))=MIN(ABS(IF(A1:A25>0,A1:A25,MAX(A1:A25)))),1,-1)*MIN(ABS(A1:A25))}`

I think the only time it wouldn't work is if all the numbers were negative, in which case it would return the number as a positive. The only way I can think of to negate this would be:

`{=IF(MAX(A1:A25)<=0,-1,IF(MIN(ABS(A1:A25))=MIN(ABS(IF(A1:A25>0,A1:A25,MAX(A1:A25)))),1,-1))*MIN(ABS(A1:A25))}`

As I said, not pretty but without VBA I can't think of a better solution; I'd love someone smarter than me to show me a better way...

**Note** The `{` curly brackets denote an array formula, you type it without the brackets and hold `Shift` + `Ctrl` while hitting `Enter` to tell Excel it is an array.

Comment: Thanks a heap. For those of us stuck with mac's the array shortcut is ⌃+⇧+Return